# method to find the the distance of two characters of a string apart and entering them into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, methods

trying to solve this question for school

"Given a string s and a character c, return a new list of integers of the same length as s where for each index i its value is set the closest distance of s[i] to c. You can assume c exists in s."

for example

Input
s = "aabaab"
c = "b"

Output
[2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

My Output
[63,63,64,63,63]

I can't figure out what im doing wrong, how should I go about it?

```
public static void main(String []Args) {
    
        String s = "aabaab";
        String c = "b";
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        int indexofc = new String(ch).indexOf(c);
        
        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
            
            int indexofothers = ch[i];
            int result = indexofothers - indexofc;
            if (result<=0) {
                result = result*(-1);
                }
            
            list.add(result);
            
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: According to your code, you should replace ```int indexofothers = ch[i];``` with ```int indexofothers = s.indexOf(ch[i]);```.  But this logic is wrong because character 
 ```c``` may appear multiple times in string ```s```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major things wrong with your code:
First of all this line makes no sense

```
int indexofothers = ch[i];
```

You are trying to get an index but are instead taking the character at the position `i` which will then be converted to an integer which can result is something like 63. So use `i` instead of `ch[i]`.

Second the indexOf method wil only return the first index if you use it like thaat. Add the current index (and move it into the loop) or otherwise you will always get the distance to the first b. So your code could look like this:

```
public static void main(String []Args) {

    String s = "aabaab";
    String c = "b";
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] ch = s.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
        int indexofc = s.indexOf(c, i);
        int result = i - indexofc;
        if (result<=0) {
            result = result*(-1);
        }
        list.add(result);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate u taking the time to help me